# Automatically add current url before print instruction in Joomla article

Tags: url, printing, joomla

I want to manually add a [Print] icon in the position of my choosing in a Joomla 3.6 article. This article will be used as a 'master' which will be copied and renamed on a weekly basis so I would like the reference to the article in the URL to be automatic. Something like this:

```html
<div class="btn-group"><a href="[html-code-for-current-article-inserted-here]?tmpl=component&amp;print=1&amp;layout=default&amp;page=" rel="nofollow" class="btn" title="Print Preview" onclick="window.open(this.href,'win2','status=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=640,height=480,directories=no,location=no'); return false;">Print Preview</a></div>
```

I tried using # to reference the current page etc but this meant that the entire content of the page was (all modules, headers, footers, etc) were displayed in the print preview as well as the current article.

Thank you.

p.s. BTW, "Joomla3.6" isn't a valid tag yet so I couldn't add it with my reputation of just 1!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your goal to "Manually add a [print] icon".

The normal way: 
In the joomla /adminstrator , in the menu under Content->article, in the options on the right, there is a "Show print icon" - option. This will show the print icon for all articles. You might need to style it to suit your need. This can also be configured on a per-menu - basis.

Optionally: 
You could override the default output of the article template ([More on output overrides here](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)) and add the print icon wherever you need it:

- Copy the file /components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php to /templates/yourtemplate/html/com_content/article/default.php
- Add the print icon somewhere: `<div class="btn-group"><a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($this->item->slug, $this->item->catid, $this->item->language)); ?>" ... >Print Preview</a></div>`

But, you can probably use the first method. Or perhaps just move the current output of the print icon in default.php, using the override method described above.

Comment: Thank you. The Joomla administrator default option places the print icon at the top right of the article and pushes the first line of the article out of alignment. I would like to place the print icon - or even just the linked word "Print" - at any point in the article with the article id added automatically as I will be re-using the article as a template.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want to achieve. You want to have the link somewhere in the article text? In that case you could make a placeholder, like ###PRINTLINK###, and replace this with the correct link in your output override, or even better in a content plugin.